# How to convert numpy.array(dtype=object) to tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

*I have imported all the required libraries for PyTorch. Here are the numpy arrays obtained from my image. And the size of my images are 150x150 grayscale images*

```
array([[array([[ 89, 117,  59, ...,  39,  48,  38],
       [118,  85,  96, ...,  41,  42,  31],
       [171, 118,  70, ...,  33,  42,  32],
       ...,
       [ 32,  49,  32, ..., 153, 181, 180],
       [ 30,  25,  28, ..., 150, 180, 185],
       [ 48,  33,  34, ..., 159, 168, 184]], dtype=uint8),
        array([0., 1.])],
       [array([[195, 192, 202, ..., 255, 254, 255],
       [206, 190, 200, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [221, 186, 192, ..., 254, 254, 255],
       ...,
       [254, 255, 255, ..., 254, 253, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8),
        array([0., 1.])],
       [array([[60, 58, 66, ..., 10, 11, 10],
       [61, 59, 56, ..., 11, 11, 11],
       [58, 53, 63, ..., 10, 11, 10],
       ...,
       [23, 45, 56, ..., 46, 38, 19],
       [71, 46, 91, ..., 34, 40, 36],
       [69, 76, 32, ..., 65, 26, 51]], dtype=uint8),
        array([1., 0.])],
       ...,
       [array([[247, 234, 231, ..., 112, 112, 114],
       [243, 229, 230, ..., 113, 114, 114],
       [236, 228, 231, ..., 118, 117, 115],
       ...,
       [ 22,  24,  24, ...,  57,  61,  61],
       [ 28,  26,  25, ...,  88,  87,  86],
       [ 30,  28,  29, ...,  92,  91,  91]], dtype=uint8),
        array([0., 1.])],
       [array([[207, 194, 195, ..., 254, 254, 255],
       [209, 199, 200, ..., 254, 255, 255],
       [199, 207, 201, ..., 254, 254, 255],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8),
        array([1., 0.])],
       [array([[ 65,  62,  72, ...,  54,  69,  53],
       [ 80,  44,  35, ...,  60,  37,  37],
       [ 75,  45,  93, ...,  43,  52,  54],
       ...,
       [ 39,  41, 106, ...,  21,  19,  18],
       [ 49,  34, 106, ...,  19,  18,  20],
       [ 42,  45,  88, ...,  19,  15,  17]], dtype=uint8),
        array([1., 0.])]], dtype=object)
```

The datatype is object and I am getting **this error:**

**TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.**

How can I convert this object dtype to supported types?

Comment: Can you add the line of code that throws this error? You may be trying to convert this to an `ndarray` somewhere...

Comment: Looks like `arr[:,0]` are 2d `uint8` arrays ,but `arr[:,1]` are (2,) shape float arrays. With a mix of array sizes this can't be turned into one numeric array or tensor.

Comment: In OpenCV Python images are represented as NumPy arrays. Which class is this object from? Is this a torchvision dataset object?

Comment: @MilindDeore These are numpy arrays of type object.

Comment: @bousof  
`print(training_data)` this shows the numpy array of type object.
**and to convert it to tensor that throws error** 

`dataset = torch.from_numpy(training_data)
dataset`

Comment: @hpaulj so is it possible to  convert it to the same array size either float or uint8?

Comment: `np.stack(arr[:,0])` and `np.stack(arr[:,1])` may work, creating two separate arrays, with their own dtype and shape.  You can't make a numeric array (or tensor) with both sizes together.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this ? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer but I'd love to hear a more computationally efficient way.
My solution was to do the following:

`my_array = numpy.array(my_array.tolist())`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
my_array.astype(int8) # or float / any other supported type
```